# How to avoid consume key-id when using upsert with autoincrement key in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, upsert

I have a table like below:

The `id` is PK and autoincrement.

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| id  |  kind  |  count |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

When i using the upsert query bleow, and 100 request that api at same time.

```
INSERT INTO Views (kind, count)
VALUES(1, 1)
ON CONFLICT(kind)
DO UPDATE SET count = count + 1
```

I'll get:

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| id  |  kind  |  count |
+-----+--------+--------+
| 100 | kind-1 |   100  |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: According to [SQLite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), autoincrement "_is usually not needed_". Perhaps review the doc and reevaluate the decision. An integer PK may be all you need. (It will not consume the id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to manipulate `sqlite_sequence` table like this:

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM Views) WHERE name="Views"
```

which will "reset" sequence to last used `id`.

This isn't, however, usefull at all. Updating `sqlite_sequence` during bulk UPSERT would for sure break performance and doing such after operation wouldn't avoid "holes" in key sequence.

Another option is to rewrite all `id`, but do you really need such?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your table was built with

```
create table Views (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  kind VARCHAR UNIQUE,
  count INTEGER
)
```

and by running 100 times the query `INSERT INTO Views (kind, count) VALUES(1, 1) ON CONFLICT(kind) DO UPDATE SET count = count + 1`, you will not get what you wrote, but

```
+-----+-------+--------+
|  id |  kind |  count |
+-----+-------+--------+
|   1 |     1 |   100  |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

The behavior that may be unwanted is that, when inserting another value (e.g. 2) with the same insert query, you will get

```
+-----+-------+--------+
|  id |  kind |  count |
+-----+-------+--------+
|   1 |     1 |   100  |
| 101 |     2 |     1  |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

Just by removing the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword in the `create table` query, you would get what I suppose you want, i.e.

```
+-----+-------+--------+
|  id |  kind |  count |
+-----+-------+--------+
|   1 |     1 |   100  |
|   2 |     2 |     1  |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

and, as @DinoCoderSaurus says, `AUTOINCREMENT` is needed only for tricky cases, *"to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows"* (SQLite doc).